# View-Model wiring up difficulties

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-2, view, model

So I have fields on my view wired up to my `base` model class like so:

```
<%= Html.TextBox("FixedRateOverride", Model.FixedRateOverride.HasValue ? Model.FixedRateOverride.Value.ToString(Chatham.Web.Data.Constants.Format.FiveDecimalPlacesFormatString) : "", new { @class = "economicTextBox", propertyName = "FixedRateOverride", onchange = "UpdateField(this);" })%>
```

What we want to do is now eliminate all of these `override` type fields that are stored on the model `base`, and wire them directly up to the actual fields on the `class` that inherits from this model `base` (there's 3 types).

The view can't inherit from any single one of them, because coming into the view, it could be any of the 3, so it has to inherit from the `base` class.

How would I wire these fields up to the fields of the specific type of `model` it is when the view only inherits from the `base`?

Comment: That looks excellent to me. It's probably not completely kosher, but so what? That's what casting is for, to solve problems like this.  And it's certainly a vast improvement over the original code.

Comment: Note: Recommend you take all of the text below **EDIT**, and post it as an answer instead of putting it in the question.

Comment: Yeah that's kind of what I was thinking. What's the point of having everything so cleanly architected if you can't make simple casts like this to solve these sorts of issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found one way to do it, but I doubt it's the most efficient or recommended way, although it might be. I change the call to the `Model` in the embedded controls to just casting it as the sub-model like so:

```
((SubModel)Model)
```

Seems to work, but like I said, looks weird, and there is probably a better way to do it, but this is my work around for now.